# Error in linearization: What is M in $| E(x,y) | \leq \frac{1}{2} M( |x-x_0 |+ |y-y_0 |)^2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've been learning about linearization in multivariable calculus. $f(x,y) \approx L(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$. and the error in this is

$| E(x,y) |  \leq  \frac{1}{2} M( |x-x_0 |+ |y-y_0 |)^2$.

I don't understand what M in this equation means. I know from my textbook that M is any upper bound for values of  $|f_{xx} |,|f_{xy}|, |f_{yy}|$ but why is that? What exactly do $|f_{xx} |,|f_{xy}|, |f_{yy}|$ mean??What happens if these values are 0? then would that mean error is 0?

Also, for $|x-x_0 |$ and $|y-y_0 |$, if a point $P(x,y,z)$ moves from $P_0(1,0,0)$ a distance of 0.1 unit towards $P_1(1,1,1)$, then would $|x-x_0 |=0, |y-y_0 |= \frac{1}{10 \sqrt{2} },|z-z_0 |= \frac{1}{10 \sqrt{2} } $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$M$ is just an arbitrary constant. The statement means there is some large enough $M$, such that the inequality will hold for all values of $(x,y)$.

> The actual error term is:
>   $$E(x,y) = \frac 12 f_{xx}(\xi, \eta)\cdot (\xi-x_0)^2 + f_{xy}(\xi, \eta)\cdot (\xi-x_0)(\eta-y_0) + \frac 12 f_{yy}(\xi, \eta)\cdot (\eta-y_0)^2$$
>   where $\xi$ and $\eta$ are values somewhere between $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)$.

The expression $|f_{xx}|$ is the absolute value of second partial derivative with respect to $x$. Typically we want to take its maximum over the values in $[x_0,x] \times [y_0,y]$ (supposing $x$ and $y$ are greater than $x_0$ respectively $y_0$).
If the second derivatives are $0$ everywhere, the error is indeed $0$.

We can find an upper estimate by taking upper estimates of absolute values everywhere:

> \begin{array}{}|E(x,y)| &\le &&\frac 12 \max_{(\xi, \eta)}|f_{xx}(\xi, \eta)|\cdot (x-x_0)^2 \\
> &&+& \phantom{\frac 12}\max_{(\xi, \eta)}|f_{xy}(\xi, \eta)|\cdot |(x-x_0)(y-y_0)| \\
> &&+& \frac 12 \max_{(\xi, \eta)}|f_{yy}(\xi, \eta)|\cdot (y-y_0)^2\end{array}

We can pick $M$ to be the largest absolute second derivative on the domain.
That is:
$$M=\max_{(\xi, \eta)}(|f_{xx}(\xi, \eta)|,\ |f_{xy}(\xi, \eta)|,\ |f_{yy}(\xi, \eta)|)$$
That means the expression turns into:
$$|E(x,y)| \le \frac 12 M\Big((x-x_0)^2 + 2|(x-x_0)(y-y_0)| + (y-y_0)^2\Big)$$
which is equal to:

> $$|E(x,y)| \le \frac 12 M\Big(|x-x_0| + |y-y_0|\Big)^2$$

Btw, your statement about $P$ moving from one point to another is correct.

Comment: How does one find the expression for E(x,y)? Is it the second term of the taylor series for multivariable functions?

Comment: @Varun: Yes and no. It's the _remainder_ term, which is very similar to the second order term. The difference is that we take it at some unknown point instead of $(x_0,y_0)$. Such a point is guaranteed to exist, so that there are no other terms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, $M$ is the largest possible value of the second derivatives at the point given.

To clarify, think about the one-dimension problem : what is the error ?

Comment: It is not about the second derivatives at the point given. Nor is it simply the largest value.

Comment: @IlikeSerena. May I ask what else did you write ?

Comment: Huh? Obviously not as much as you did on this particular forum. What does that mean?

Comment: @IlikeSerena. This is just because I got three downvotes for my short answer ! Cheers :)